# How to tune the onFocus auto scroll distance?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiview, uitextfield

I am trying to tune the auto scroll distance of the default IOS behaviour.
[image]

As shown in the picture, by default, the screen will scroll automatically up so that the key board won't hide the section you are editing.
But the problem with this is that it only scrolls up high enough so that the top of the key board overlapping on the bottom of the cell.

What I want is something like this:

[image]

So instead of just moving up till the keyboard won't cover the textField, it should move up some extra space so that the next textField could be seen as well.

Ok, now I finish the description. Here is what I have tried.
1. I have tried to delegate the didSelectRowAtIndexPath to roll up the table view.
2. I have tried to use a tap gesture recognizer to handle the tapPosition and then scroll.

These two methods actually works to some extent but they are still not 100% what I want. Because once I tap focus on text field the table view still not moved high enough so that I can see the next field. (It seems to me that the textFields focus on event has higher priority than the tap gesture and cell selection)

Now this is what I want, I was wondering if there is a way to tune the default scroll up behaviour on focus of the text field.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try scrollView setContentOffSet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    self.activeTextField = textField;
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3f];
    [self.scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0.0, self.activeTextField.frame.origin.y-92) animated:YES]; // change the value "92" as per your scroll height.
        [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Comment: It works fine on the second tap, which means if I tap focus directly after the table view load the whole view is still just moving up a little bit. But if I tap focus on some other text field first and then tap on the last text field then my scroll configuration is loaded (the code you suggested). My guest is that some keyboard show/hide default has higher priority than this method you mentioned. But thanks anyway.